# Is there a way to get iMacros version

Tags: python, firefox, web-scraping, imacros

I've developed a Python program years ago which does some web scraping by producing iMacros script for Firefox. The site which script was developed for, had undergone a lot of redesign so I have to update the script and I also want that script to be more general for later uses. The problem is; when I had a look at my Python program, I saw that it directly writes to the output file (which is a iMacros script) the iMacros version number like: 
`VERSION BUILD=7021019`. My question is, if there's a possible way to learn iMacros version on the fly from the Firefox?

Comment: Can you find something out from this. http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox

Comment: Nope. Already read it.

Comment: If you are recording a macro with iMacros it automatically gives you the version . But if you are creating a code outside of iMacros then you can create it yourself. Just use the latest iMacros version.

Comment: I'have already written a Python program to create the iMacros script for me. Question is that iMacros is continually updating itself and the resulting iM scripts produced by my Python program shows outdated version information.

Comment: Then make a python script to go on imacros site and get the latest version.

Comment: How one can be sure that the Firefox which the iMacros script is produced for, has the latest iMacros installed?

Comment: Because if you enable the automatic update the FireFox will get the latest iMacros addon version.